# How to run scripts at the time of plugin installation in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I have written an eclipse plugin which will work as an editor for some kind of files. But I need to run some system commands before the installation of plugin.

I am planing to create a batch file with those commands and run it at the time of installation. So is it possible to run some java code which will execute my batch file at the time of plugin installation ?

Comment: In Eclipse plug-ins are lazy loaded: the Java code of a plug-in is loaded and executed not before a feature is used. Is it also possible for you to execute your scripts before it is used the first time?

Comment: Sounds great idea. But where to write those codes which will get executed when the plugin is used first time?

Comment: You could put your code into the [activator class](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/overview.htm) and have a [preference](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_load_and_save_plug-in_preferences%3F) of _[ConfigurationScope](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_preference_scope%3F)_ like _scriptInitDone_ to make sure the script is executed only the first time (not every time Eclipse is started and Java code of your plug-in is used)